# How to Count on same column with filtering other column in Select

Tags: sql-server

How we can count same column by filterin SQL Server:

Here Table:

```
id CodeType Code 
1   I        C001
1   I        M002
2   I        C002 
2   M        M003
3   I        C002 
3   M        M003
```

Sql output should like this:

```
Count WHEN CodeType I and Code  C001 with M002  :1
Count WHEN CodeType I and Code  C002 with M003  :2
```

How Can we do this with SQL Server

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Select CodeType, Code, Count(id) as countid
    from tablename
    group by CodeType, Code

Comment: Why do you say there are 2 "WHEN CodeType I and Code  C002 with M003" when both M003 rows have CodeType M?   You'll need to explain the logic behind your desired results, as it is not self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets make the example data:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
( 
    id INT,
    CodeType VARCHAR(1),
    Code VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
( id, CodeType, Code )
VALUES
(1,   'I',        'C001'),
(1,   'I',        'M002'),
(2,   'I',        'C002'),
(2,   'M',        'M003'),
(3,   'I',        'C002'),
(3,   'M',        'M003');
```

Now that we have the data, it looks like you want to find the corresponding M records for each C record (based on ID) and once you get the sets, you are looking for duplicates. You are also checking if the C records type is an 'I'

```
SELECT c.CodeType, c.Code, m.Code, COUNT(*) AS GrpCnt
FROM @MyTable c
INNER JOIN @MyTable m
    ON c.id = m.id
    AND c.Code LIKE 'C%'
    AND m.Code LIKE 'M%'
WHERE c.CodeType = 'I'
GROUP BY c.CodeType, c.Code, m.Code
```

Here is the output:

```
CodeType    Code    Code    GrpCnt
I   C001    M002    1
I   C002    M003    2
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try using COUNT(*) OVER (Partition by )

```
create table #test(id int,CodeType char(1),Code char(4))

insert into #test values(1,'I','C002')
insert into #test values(2,'M','M003')
insert into #test values(3,'M','M003')

select id,CodeType,Code,count(*) over (partition by codetype,code) as cnt from #test
```